# EOF inside string in big data

Tags: python, csv, pandas, import-from-csv

From iPython I run a read_csv on a relatively huge set of data (1gb++)

I am returned with

> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 891743

I know there is an error with reading a particular string within the data but I just cannot dive down into detail to correct the error.

With reference from:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5500

He dives down to the data level and corrects it there. But due to the size of the data I am working on, I cannot seem to get an idea on how I can correct the issue. I really cannot do the same.

Comment: Why can't you do the same? Because the file is big? Some editors should have no problems with that. E.g. `vim filename`, then `:891743<CR>`, then see if there is a `^Z` there or something. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Faster_loading_of_large_files

Comment: hi! Thanks, let me give it a go and see if this works out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, type into the terminal:

```
head -n891743 <filename> | tail -n1 > out
```

This will write the 891743th row of your csv file into the "out" file.